# can't run sql backup script on shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, sql, backup, shared-hosting

I can't run SQL backup script on shared hosting through asp.net website

This is the error message:

> BACKUP DATABASE permission denied in database 'TestDB'.
>
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

This is the code:

```
sqlcon.Open();
//query to take backup database
sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database TestDB to disk='" + destdir + "\\" +  dbname + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyy") + ".Bak'", sqlcon);
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//Close connection
sqlcon.Close();
```

Comment: Do you have diskspace on the local disk at your shared hoster available? You **cannot** backup a remote database onto your own local harddisk in your computer - only to a disk on that remote server - and that's typically not included in those packages...

Answer (score 1):

The user account you are connecting with doesn't have the permission to do a backup.

(That's what the error says)

Only users who are members of `db_owner` or `db_backupoperator` have the `backup database` permission by default.

Your hosting provider will probably provide some other backup mechanism.